# Tangency principle for minimal hypersurfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, elliptic-equations, minimal-surfaces

Let $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ be two properly embedded complete connected minimal surfaces (without boundary) in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $p \in \Sigma_1 \cap \Sigma_2 \ne \emptyset $.

It is well known that if $\Sigma_1$ lies on one side of $\Sigma_2$, then $\Sigma_1 = \Sigma_2$. (See for instance **Corollary 1.28** of *A Course in Minimal Surfaces*, by Colding & Minicozzi).

Can I have the same conclusion assuming that at the contact point $p$ the surfaces agree up to the second order (without assuming that one lies above the other)?

Any help will be very apreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I guess it must be false, because this kind of "tangengy principle" does not apply in the (easier) case of harmonic functions. Indeed the polynomial $p(x,y) = x^3 - 3y^2 x$ is harmonic and at $(0,0)$ coincides up to the second order with the constant function $0$.

Comment: thanks, very interesting counterexample! I have a question, what could we say for the high generalization of "minimal surface", i.e. solution with $\sigma_k (D(\frac{Du}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla u|^2}}))=0$ with suitable boundary condition whatever. Could we have the similar conclusion?

Comment: The maximum principle isn't going to help if there's no maximum :)

Comment: @TedShifrin I do agree. And I'm convinced that it must be false. But are there counterexample? I mean, is there any minimal surface which (at least at one point) touches its tangent place up to the second order?